# mongoose query, find where array of tags id includes at least one id from query tags array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have article schema :

```
const schema = new Schema({
   title: {
        type: String,
        unique: true, 
        required: [true, 'Title is required'],
    }, 
    slug: {  
        type: String, 
        slug: "title", 
        slugPaddingSize: 2,  
        unique: true 
    },
   editor: {
      type: String
   },
    duration: {
      type: String
   },
    image: Object,
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    language: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Language' },
    level: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Level' },
    tag: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }]
},{
    timestamps: true
})
```

Need to find every articles which tag contains at least one of tag id from req.query params (it can be also array of id's or just single id).

Thanks

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: something like that const result = await Article.find({tag: ['6315ad3a0f23a0d74f25567a', '6315ad480f23a0d74f25568e']})

Comment: find articles which tags contains at least one id from query params

Comment: You need to use `$in` operator. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/